# VueJS/JavaScript: плагин для генерации документа

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Сразу прошу прощения, возможно это не так называется, но я не знаю, как правильно. Может из-за этого и не могу нагуглить. Суть: мне надо иметь возможность создать документ на базе того, что введет или выберет пользователь. Постараюсь описать пример:

Я, **поле ввода**, **выпадающий список** рождения, проживаю в г. **поле ввода** и т.д.

Суть думаю понятна. И после этого мне надо сохранить этот текст. По сути, генерировать сам документ не надо, я это уже сделаю на стороне сервера.

Может есть какой то плагин, что бы в нужный местах указать что надо?

Спасибо

Comment: ` ```Я, ${this.полеВводаModel}, ${this.выпадающийСписокРожденияModel}, проживаю в г. ${this.полеВводаModel} и т.д.``` `

Comment: Вместо `чтоугодноModel` подразумеваются свойства (в `data`, к которым через `v-model` реактивно привязаны `value` html-контролов)... Ну и, поместить упомянутую шаблонную строку стоит в [вычисляемое свойство](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) или метод инстанса Vue.

Comment: суть не в том, что я не знаю, как подставить значение, а в том, что там надо подставить либо input либо select

Comment: _«там надо подставить либо input либо select»_ - а какая логика предполагается у выбора между `input` и `select`?

Comment: это уже я должен ставить сам. просто что бы потом на выходе по слову input появился инпут, а по слову select - дропдаун. думал, может есть что то готовое, что бы свое не писать

Comment: Готовое упомянуто выше, это шаблонные строковые литералы ES6 и вычисляемые свойства Vue. Их достаточно для решения задачи генерации практически любого неразмеченного текста.